# How do I use a custom formula to filter dates to a specific year in a pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a sheet of expenses with the date in the first column, in the form YYYY-MM-DD. The column name is "date". I know that I can use the "is between" value filter to select dates within a certain year, but is it possible to use the `YEAR()` function directly, e.g., `YEAR(date)=2022`? When I use that formula, no values are returned (even though the data has plenty of dates within 2022).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `YEAR(date)=2022` will be treated as a text string rather than as a formula. To enter a formula, start it with an equals sign, like this:

`=year(date) = 2022`